# TaxonomyFields in SPFx

Tags: reactjs, taxonomy, spfx

Currently I'm creating a new form in SPFx. When reading the fields of the list there is an taxonomyField. 
I'm using the PnP Taxonomy control to display the taxonomy labels.

I would like to get the termset id from the taxonomy field and using the following code

```
                  var taxField = field as SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField;
                  ctx.load(taxField);
                  await new Promise((resolveTax, rejectTax) => {
                    ctx.executeQueryAsync(()=> {
                      let termSetID = taxField.get_termSetId();
                      console.log(termSetID);
                      resolveTax();
                    }, (sender,args) =>{
                      console.log("Could not retrieve taxonomyfield termsset id: " + args.get_message());
                      rejectTax();
                    });
                  });
                }
```

I Always receive the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'TaxonomyField' of undefined
    at eval (eval at Type.parse (https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:10143), :1:13)
    at Function.Type.parse (https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:10143)
    at SP.ClientRequest.$3K_0 (https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.Runtime.js:2:51794)
    at Array. (https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:307)
    at https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:51370
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:89652)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (https://...sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js:5:84251)

Anybody a suggestion to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use open source tools to work with SharePoint's `Taxonomy`, for example [react-taxonomypicker](https://github.com/jquintozamora/react-taxonomypicker)

This is an elegant `Taxonomy Picker` control built with `TypeScript` for `React`. Initially built for use in Office 365 / SharePoint.

[image]

**Features:**

- Retrieve Terms from a Term Set by Term Set GUID.
- Support for large Term Set using Async mode
- Use SP.Taxonomy.js
- Use Promise (polyfill it if needed IE)

You can test it here: https://jquintozamora.github.io/react-taxonomypicker/